# How to connect to Google cloud Storage via ADF using Service Account key

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating a Linked Service to connect to Google Cloud Storage and i am using following JSON file for Service account that has access on the Google Cloud Storage

[image]

I am using private_key_id as Access Key ID and private_key value as Secret Access Key and Service URL as https://storage.googleapis.com:

[image]

Linked Service is failing with following error:

[image]

How to create a Linked Service using this JSON file to connect to Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0):

Does this documentation help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-cloud-storage?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties